# How can I avoid the following race condition using condition variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition, synchronous

I have a recipe of several steps where each steps may or may not control a motor. For this, I created a thread that sends a command to the motor. I used to join that thread, as each steps needed to complete before going to the next one, but recently, I have a task of implementing a "Go to next step". The problem is that I cannot simply stop the motor upon clicking that button. The motor should only stop if the next step contains another movement. If that next step didn't move the motor, we wouldn't want to stop the motor.

For this, I created two variables, one that is set to true if the motor thread finished his movement, another that is set to true if a signal to go to the next step is received :

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool signalReceived = false;
bool threadFinished = false;

void moveMotor() {
    // If current step moves motor, stop any ongoing movement
    // ...
    // If current step moves motor, move the motor
    // ...

    // Set the threadFinished flag to true when the thread finishes
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    threadFinished = true;
    signalReceived = false;
    cv.notify_one();
}

void signalHandler() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    signalReceived = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        std::thread motorThread(moveMotor);
        motorThread.detach();

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        cv.wait(lock, [] { return threadFinished || signalReceived; });

        if (threadFinished) {
            std::cout << "The motor thread has finished." << std::endl;
        }
        if (signalReceived) {
            std::cout << "A signal was received." << std::endl;
        }

        // Reset the flags for the next iteration
        threadFinished = false;
        signalReceived = false;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I unfortunately have an issue with the above code. Let's have the following example :

1. In the first iteration (first step for example), a signal is emitted, and therefor, the main continues on to the second iteration .
2. In the second iteration , upon detaching the second thread, the first iteration thread finally finishes, setting the `threadFinished` variable to true. The second iteration will continue as if the second thread finished, which is not what I want.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Its not excatly clear what you are asking, but if you care only about last thread's finish and don't want to set `threadFinished` by all previous threads, then you can for example save latest thread id in variable and check if this id matches current thread id before setting `threadFinished`.

Comment: You likely want a single dedicated thread to control the motor, and send commands to it via a producer-consumer queue.